# Remote R repo with very long password

Tags: r

I know that remote R repos can be added via:

```
local({
    r <- list("internal-repo" = "https://username:password@remote.repo.com/")
    options(repos = r)
})
```

this worked for us for several years. But now my company introduced for technical users a new password policy, leading to very long passwords. This leads when installing a package to:

```
2: In gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file '/tmp/RtmpQA3EHC/repos_https%3A%2F%2Ftechuser% ... verylongstring ...%remote.repo%2Fsrc%2Fcontrib.rds', probable reason 'File name too long'
```

How do we avoid this problem? Preferably without using any other package management system.

Comment: Exactly how many characters long are these new usernames and passwords?

Comment: This may _not_ be the best reason to do an upgrade, but R-4.3 now supports paths of more than 260 characters when enabled on the OS, see [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem. I forgot to mention that the problem occurs on Linux. The release notes only mention Windows.